# EF4: updating a disconnected entity and inserting a related entity

Tags: entity-framework-4

I would like to achieve the following:

A service is called with a DTO as parameter. I would like to know the simplest way to save the changes if that DTO consists in an existing entity with a modification (Parent with an update) and a related entity which is new (child with an insert).

Thanks in advance